# Python - Format array into a list with a reference number

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing, format

im learning python, and i have the next problem and can't find any solution, could you help me?

I have 2 variables:

"reference" is the id of each member in the "names" array.
"names" is a array with names separated by comma, and in this same array i have a date of birth.

```
def printSubjects(bin_to_id):
    for reference, names in bin_to_id.items():
        namelist = str(names)
        print(reference, namelist)
```

The result is like:

```
28705 ([Jonh Daves, George Denis, Alan Denis], ['1988-03-13', '1989-03-04'])
28995 ([Ophelia James, David Daves, Alex Jonson], ['1998-03-15'])
```

But i need to get the next format using `print()`:

```
28705|Jonh Daves|1988-03-13
28705|Jonh Daves|1989-03-04
28705|Alan Denis|1989-03-04
28705|Alan Denis|1988-03-13
28705|George Denis|1989-03-04
28705|George Denis|1988-03-13
28995|Ophelia James|1998-03-15
28995|David Daves|1998-03-15
28995|Alex Jonson|1998-03-15
```

someone can help me or give me an idea to how can do it?

I appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: Could you post the `bin_to_id` dictionary as well?

Comment: Post your input so we can get an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the input dictionary looks like this -

```
{
    28705: (["Jonh Daves", "George Denis", "Alan Denis"], ['1988-03-13', '1989-03-04']),
    28995: (["Ophelia James", "David Daves", "Alex Jonson"], ['1998-03-15'])
}
```

Based on this assumption, I am confused as to why you are using `namelist = str(names)` in your loop. I have removed that line from the loop since it doesn't help to answer your question. Here is the updated function -

```
def printSubjects(bin_to_id):
    for reference, namesDates in bin_to_id.items():
        # namelist = str(names)
        names, dates = namesDates # Unpack the names list and the dates list
        for name in names: # Iterate through names
            for date in dates: # Iterate through dates
                print(reference, "|", name, "|", date)
```

Output

```
28705 | Jonh Daves | 1988-03-13
28705 | Jonh Daves | 1989-03-04
28705 | George Denis | 1988-03-13
28705 | George Denis | 1989-03-04
28705 | Alan Denis | 1988-03-13
28705 | Alan Denis | 1989-03-04
28995 | Ophelia James | 1998-03-15
28995 | David Daves | 1998-03-15
28995 | Alex Jonson | 1998-03-15
```

As an example, for the key `28795`, the variable `namesDates` is `(["Jonh Daves", "George Denis", "Alan Denis"], ['1988-03-13', '1989-03-04'])`.

Using `names, dates = namesDates` we unpack namesDates, such that `names` is `["Jonh Daves", "George Denis", "Alan Denis"]` and `dates` is `['1988-03-13', '1989-03-04']`. Then, using two for loops, we iterate though names, and for each name, we iterate though all the dates.

Comment: Thanks for your help, one last thing.. the [] values are discarted, how can get this information too?

Comment: I've Solved using the following code:         if not dates: dates = ['None']  ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Glad that the answer helped. Please mark this as the correct answer if it helped you to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

It Works!!!, but now i have a problem with the values who don´t have date like:

```
 1234 ([Jonh, Paul, Richard] , [])
```

these records dissapear from the output, how can use them?

```
Output: 

1234|Jon|None
1234|Paul|None
1234|Richard|None

or:

1234|Jon|
1234|Paul|
1234|Richard|
```

Thanks!!!

Update:

```
def printSubjects(bin_to_id):
    for reference, names in bin_to_id.items():
        names, dates = names
        if not dates: # For values null or empy assign a 'None' Value
            dates = ['None']
        for name in names:
            for date in dates:
                print(reference, name, date)
                with open('List.txt', 'a') as file: # Write the output into a txt file with the following format.
                    print(reference, "|", name, "|", date, file=file)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly revisit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how answers at Stack Overflow work. Your Answer should contain only the answer-part, not a new Question. Nor half a new Question / half an Answer.